# Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dotnetopenauth

I've just started using dotnetopenauth for my user registration. It's great, and is working perfectly.

The problem is now I'm getting an error when I try to go to /Home/ which says:

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.
>
> The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
> OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc.Controllers.HomeController
> YourApp.Controllers.HomeController

The problem is, I have *no idea* where OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc.Controllers.Homecontroller is coming from. I can't find ANY instance of "OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc" anywhere in my app, save 2 places, both of which occur in the UsersController:

```
OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
```

I've tried deleting the DLL and rebuilding the app - no change. I can't figure out where this other controller would be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you copied the code from the samples into your codebase or you are referencing the DLL from the DotNetOpenAuth **sample** project. Note, *OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc* is the namespace of the MVC example.

So my suggestion is to first remove all instances of the DotNetOpenAuth library by starting from the project references.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error message after changing the name and default namespace of the project.

Finally the solution was to manually delete all the files from debug -folder ("Clean Solution"-function of VS didn't help in this case).

Comment: That's what I needed to fix my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this in route.config file

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "ProjectName.Controllers" }
);
```

Note: Project Name which you had given while creating the project